# VB.NET how to pass value on database in function

Tags: database, vb.net, visual-studio, function

sorry for this noob question. 
I just want to know what is the correct syntax for this ? 
I just want to return the statement if its true or false.

I have this function

```
Private Sub InsertTest(ByVal StudentID As Integer, ByVal SubjectID As Integer)
    Dim dr As MySqlDataReader
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand
    Dim myconn As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;Database=csais;User ID=root;Password=;")
    myconn.Open()

    Dim Query = "Select student_id,sub_id FROM student_subject WHERE student_id = @student_id AND sub_id = @sub_id"
    cmd = New MySqlCommand(Query, myconn)
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
    If dr.Read = True Then
        MessageBox.Show("This statement is true")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("This statement is false")
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    InsertTest(2009500083, 1)
End Sub
```

If i replace the @student_id by 2009500083 and @sub_id by 1
it will return true. If not 
I have an error in 
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

> Fatal error encountered during command execution.

What is the correct syntax for passing the value in function ?? THank you.

Comment: The problem is that you were using parameter placeholders in the SQL code, i.e. `@student_id` and `@sub_id`, but you never added the corresponding parameters to your command object. It sounds like your solution is not the best option. The proper fix would have been to add the appropriate parameters. There are loads of places that you can learn how to use parameters with ADO.NET code.

Comment: By the way, you also never close your connection object or your data reader, which is bad. ideally, you would use `Using` statements to create the connection object and the data reader. In that case, they will each be closed implicitly at the end of the block.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't really make sense anyway, so I hope it was just a test. You are retrieving only the columns that you specify in the `WHERE` clause, so you will only ever get the same values back that you put in. Not useful in a real-world scenario. It also seems odd to have only a `SELECT` in a method named `InsertTest`. Again, presumably just for testing but still unnecessarily confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You are using parameters in your select statement so you need to add them to command's parameters collection. Of course you need the Using...End Using blocks.

```
Private Sub InsertTest(ByVal StudentID As Integer, ByVal SubjectID As Integer)
    Dim RetVal As Integer
    Using myconn As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;Database=csais;User ID=root;Password=;")
        Dim Query = "Select Count(*) FROM student_subject WHERE student_id = @student_id AND sub_id = @sub_id"
        Using cmd As New MySqlCommand(Query, myconn)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@student_id", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = StudentID
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@sub_id", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = SubjectID
            myconn.Open()
            RetVal = CInt(cmd.ExecuteScalar)
        End Using
    End Using
    If RetVal = 1 Then
        MessageBox.Show("This statement is true")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("This statement is false")
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but if in case someone wonders here like me. This is the answer

```
Private Sub InsertTest(ByVal StudentID As Integer, ByVal SubjectID As Integer)
    Dim dr As MySqlDataReader
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand
    Dim myconn As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;Database=csais;User ID=root;Password=;")
    myconn.Open()

    Dim Query = "Select student_id,sub_id FROM student_subject WHERE student_id = @student_id AND sub_id = @sub_id"
    cmd = New MySqlCommand(Query, myconn)
    
    '====================================================
    ' this is where he missed it, you need to add your parameter
    ' you forgot to pass the parameters

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@student_id ", StudentID)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sub_id", SubjectID)

    '====================================================
   
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
    If dr.Read = True Then
        MessageBox.Show("This statement is true")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("This statement is false")
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    InsertTest(2009500083, 1)
End Sub
```